# iWork Problem Under Lion

Tags: iwork

After installing Lion the iWork applications no longer have a "Save As" command in the file menu.  It is common that I want to use an existing document, save it as a different file name, and then modify it.  I'm sure I can make a copy but that's more work than it's worth. The help file continues to insist that there is a "Save As" feature in the File menu.

Answer (score 1):

In the File menu below `Save...` or `Save a Version` you have an option called `Duplicate`.
This opens a new window with the current state of the file you're editing and you can now use `File > Save...` to save it with different file name.

Answer (score 1):

The "Save As" feature has been replaced by [Lion's new Versions feature](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/auto-save.html).

You have to perform more steps now though, because first you need to `Duplicate` the document

[image: Duplicate Menu entry in Keynote]

a new version will "jump" out of the current document.

You'll notice that `Save` in the File menu is now changed to `Save...`

[image: Save... Menu entry in Keynote]

I'm pretty sure that "Save as" will return shortly as this doesn't exactly make the process any easier...